# How to determine DC Amperes required for Amplifier?

Tags: amplifier, powering

I'm trying to understand if there's any relationship between the rated wattage (RMS) of an audio amplifier and the corresponding power requirements on its power supply.

Practically, if I buy an amplifier that does not have its own power supply, is there any formula or inference I can make to help me determine the minimum wattage of the (bench) power supply I should purchase?

To provide an example, consider the following [cheap amplifier](https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B01MQHJW6X/ref=sspa_dk_detail_8?pd_rd_i=B01IXVKF9I&th=1) and a power supply such as [this one](https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B077N22T6L/ref=sspa_dk_detail_9?psc=1&pd_rd_i=B077N22T6L&pf_rd_m=A3DWYIK6Y9EEQB&pf_rd_p=dd8bce25-0727-4a5d-b121-eef3dd7bc606&pd_rd_wg=t4t7Z&pf_rd_r=HHGV2QPD9QZQEAYY47WK&pf_rd_s=desktop-dp-sims&pf_rd_t=40701&pd_rd_w=XLTQB&pf_rd_i=desktop-dp-sims&pd_rd_r=d6d54581-ed83-11e8-8ab7-d7d92181ecc1). Is it powerful enough? Not powerful enough? How can I tell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your amplifier is capable of delivering 240 Watts of energy.

Power (Watts) = Voltage (volts) x Current (amps)

Therefore the current range is:

Power/Voltage = Current

- 240 W / 12 V = 20 A
- 240 W / 26 V = 9 A

So when powering the amplifier from a higher voltage, you are likely to require less overall current.

Maximum current drain at maximum power is 20A

The amplifier board indicates 90% efficiency, so you may well need to factor this in:

- (240/12)/0.9 = 22

So in order to deliver 240 Watts you may need to supply 22 Amps.

Looks like that PSU will probably be good enough to power that amplifier board.

Comment: Thanks Mark, your caclulations seem straightfoward and easy to understand. I think, as in many things, these are all in a sense "worst case scenarios", in that the amplifier won't be delivering peak power 100% of the time, or for very long, so these are "safe" maximums, is that an accurate statement?

Comment: Yes. That is an accurate statement. Note in the specs the difference between "peak" output and "RMS" output. RMS is "square root of mean of squares of instantaneous values".